# Animated javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

So I wrote a very simple html/js script to be used in OBS (Open Broadcaster Software):

http://8wayrun.tv/scripts/sf4.html

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#file1").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1500);
    $("#file2").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#vs').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 500});
        $('#vs').animate({ width: "300", top: "160", left: "490" }, 500);
    }, 1500);
}, 1000);
```

The problem with this is that jQuery and jQuery-UI I gigantic libraries. Loading up half a meg of libraries in OBS causes some severe performance issues. As you can see, I am doing some pretty simple stuff. I was wondering if someone could help me get this function running without the use of any external libraries. I need it to run as smooth as possible as I broadcast in 60fps.

Comment: Why aren't you using a CDN? Jjquery and jquery ui offer them on their homepage. Also Google hosts these libs

Comment: I don't think you need jQuery UI for this anyways.

Comment: I dont see what that has to do with my issue. CDN or not, I still have to load up half a meg of libraries into OBS. Using a CDN instead of loading it up locally in OBS is actually bad too; because its not as fast in a situation that needs instant loading.

Comment: Not sure how against libraries you are but http://greensock.com/tweenlite -> download button, check lightweight, is ~60-65kb

Comment: For CSS animation, this could help: http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: I'm not adverse to libraries, as long as they are lightweight. I found something called "minifiedjs" that is only 21kb. Would you guys recommend this?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod I think it looks alright

Comment: Not sure where you're getting half a meg of libraries.  A minified jQuery download is like 90k and even smaller if gzipped.  You shouldn't need jQuery UI for what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure css alternative (Fluid, fast and easy):

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0;}

:root,body{
    position:relative;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: ghostwhite;
}

main,figure{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}
main{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0
}
figure{
    position:relative
}
figure img:nth-child(1){
    animation: introLeft .6s ease
}
figure img:nth-child(2){
    transform:scaleX(-1);
    animation: introRight .6s ease
}
figure img:nth-child(3){
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;
    animation: introScale .9s ease
}
figure img:not(:nth-child(3)){
    width:48%
}

@keyframes introLeft {
    from{transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0)}
    to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
}

@keyframes introRight {
    from{transform:translate3d(100%,0,0) scaleX(-1)}
    to{transform:translate3d(0,0,0) scaleX(-1)}
}
@keyframes introScale {
    0%{transform:scale(4);opacity:0}
    80%{transform:scale(4);opacity:0}
    100%{transform:scale(1);opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <figure>
      <img src=http://i.imgur.com/9iHCndo.png />
      <img src=http://i.imgur.com/ARZv1dy.png />
      <img src=http://i.imgur.com/Q2jTGlE.png />
  </figure>
</main>
```